Major error/misprint in introduction of Oxford World Classics AKJV with Apocrypha or am I missing something?
I recently acquired the Oxford World Classic’s edition of the Authorized King James Version of the Bible with the Apocrypha. I was reading through the introduction when I stumbled upon this very odd and seemingly incorrect passage:

To begin with, as we have just seen, this loose collection of very different kinds of material composed over a period of almost 500 years—including in the Old Testament, history, prophecy, law, devotional verse, proverbs, and even love poetry and fiction, as well as, in the New Testament, letters from named individuals—all had to be placed in a specific order.


I know very well that the academic consensus on the length of the period in which the entire Bible was composed is roughly 1,300 to 1,500 years, and here in the text, it appears to me that it is stating that it is 500 years. Am I misreading, misinterpreting, or is this a printing error or simply a boldfaced error (in which case I do not feel comfortable moving on with the rest of this edition)?

Welcome to Christianity! Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

That it is part of the Oxford World's Classics series is a good clue as to what this book is about.
The advertising blurb indicates that it is intended for an audience interested in ancient literature and the historical development of the Bible from a non-religious perspective:

The Bible is the most important book in the history of Western civilization, and also the most difficult to interpret.
It has been the vehicle of continual conflict, with every interpretation reflecting passionately held views that have affected not merely religion, but politics, art, and even science.
This unique edition offers an exciting new approach to the most influential of all English biblical texts--the Authorized King James Version, complete with the Apocrypha.
Its wide-ranging Introduction and the substantial notes to each book of the Bible guide the reader through the labyrinth of literary, textual, and theological issues, using the most up-to-date scholarship to demonstrate how and why the Bible has affected the literature, art and general culture of the English-speaking world.
About the Series: For over 100 years Oxford World's Classics has made available the broadest spectrum of literature from around the globe.
Each affordable volume reflects Oxford's commitment to scholarship, providing the most accurate text plus a wealth of other valuable features, including expert introductions by leading authorities, voluminous notes to clarify the text, up-to-date bibliographies for further study, and much more.
— The Bible: Authorized King James Version With Apocrypha (Oxford World's Classics) 1st Edition

The book's long introduction makes this position even more obvious.
The Old Testament was based on legends and tales of earlier peoples, the New Testament appropriated those scriptures as the basis of the new religion of Christianity, much later, the translators of the King James version added their own biases when turning it into English, and more recently it has been interpreted and translated from newer viewpoints.
E.g.:

… the Christian project of appropriating the Jewish scriptures and presenting itself as the heir to Judaism …
…
For example, the existing cultic language of Judaism could be given a new life by making it refer figuratively to events in the New Testament.
Thus, the Old Testament idea of sacrifice was reapplied in relation to the
crucifixion. By identifying Jesus with the sacrificial Passover lamb of
Jewish ritual not merely was the idea of sacrifice being given a new
focal point and meaning, but in addition a rich vein of figurative pastoral typology was simultaneously being opened up and appropriated
from the Hebrew scriptures to link with similar imagery in the New Testament
…
Enlightenment criticism and historicization, together with the Romantic reaction, gave to the Age of Revolution a new vocabulary and
rhetoric—even in some cases a new agenda. Each changed reading
in the light of new circumstances took as its text an earlier change—
in what we are now beginning to realize is a tradition with no visible
first point. The Bible is apparently a holy book without an ur-text;
instead, there are only endless layers of appropriation. But whereas
readers of the past frequently regarded it as the supreme example of
God's unchanging message to his people, the modern reader has had
to learn to see it as something more of a moving target. If for some
that has been sufficient to undermine any authority it may have once
possessed, for others it may be an illustration of its continuing dynamism and vitality.
It is certainly sufficient to establish its categorical uniqueness.
— The Bible

If you want an atheistic historical view of the Bible as a work of literature, one whose interpretation changes with time, this is probably a good book.

Am I misreading, misinterpreting, …

No. You are correctly reading what they wrote, and correctly interpreting what they meant to say.
As to the 500 years, which I initially neglected to directly address:

Part of the skeptical/atheist position is to assume a relatively late date of composition of the Old Testament.
Among other things this resolves the problem of prophecies by assuming they must have been written after the events in question (which of course is circular reasoning).
— user111403

See Michael16's answer to this question for a good background of the authors' view of the origins of the Bible.

But what I am confused about is what they are referring to with the 500 years?

@MattHarper part of the skeptical/atheist position is to assume a relatively late date of composition of the Old Testament. Among other things this resolves the problem of prophecies by assuming they must have been written after the events in question (which of course is circular reasoning).

The earliest anyone will claim the entire cannon to have been completed is around 100CE.  Is the Oxford World Classic edition claiming that it wasn't started until 400BCE?  Assuming that prophecies were written at that point is one thing, but isn't there a general consensus that the Pentateuch began centuries before that (from material that was yet older still)?  Or perhaps their "500 years" starts from when there were two separate scrolls and someone had to decide on an arbitrary order, since the rest of the paragraph is talking about the ordering of the books of the bible.

@Teepeemm — The introduction says "material composed over a period of almost 500 years".  "Composed" is a much stronger (and less correct) claim than "compiled" or "canonicalized".

I don't see how you're answering the original question.  Are you saying Oxford could be correct from a atheist position with the composition occurring from -400 to 100?  Or that Oxford is incorrect because even the atheist position doesn't specify such a narrow timeframe?  "Compiled" or "canonicalized" is indeed a weaker claim in that it allows a later start date, but that's the only way I can see 500 years being possible.

@Teepeemm, I'm saying they have a very non-religious view of the Bible, and their underlying theme is how the text was combined from many different cultures and was changed many times. They definitely present a picture where before 400 BCE there was no such thing as the Bible, only various collections of stories and legends.

Some scholars who believe that the Hebrew Bible was written over a relatively short timespan, such as around 500 years, include proponents of various theories that place the composition of the texts within a constrained historical period. This perspective is often associated with the "minimalist" or "revisionist" school of biblical scholarship. This edition has received good reviews, and I am sure you will learn something new or different, as the focus is mainly literary and its impact on human civilization rather than theological. You should inquire more about the Bible editions you're purchasing beforehand, to avoid the disappointment.
Wikipedia states:

Biblical minimalism, also known as the Copenhagen School because two of its most prominent figures taught at Copenhagen University, is a movement or trend in biblical scholarship that began in the 1990s with two main claims:

that the Bible cannot be considered reliable evidence for what had happened in ancient Israel; and
that "Israel" itself is a problematic subject for historical study.


Key Points of the Short Timespan View
Unified Composition: These scholars argue that the bulk of the Hebrew Bible was written during a specific and relatively unified historical period, typically around the late 7th to early 5th centuries BCE.
This view is based on historical, linguistic, and archaeological evidence that suggests a more concentrated period of literary activity, especially during and after the Babylonian exile.
Exilic and Post-Exilic Period:
Many proponents of this theory place significant emphasis on the Babylonian exile (586-539 BCE) and the subsequent Persian period as key times for the composition and redaction of the biblical texts. They argue that the socio-political and religious upheavals of these periods provided the impetus for the recording and editing of Israel's religious traditions and historical narratives.
